# Change card view clickable property programmatically

Tags: android, radio-button, android-cardview, clickable

how can I change the card view  clickable property from true to false at run time for example when the "A" radio button checked I want to display new items and clickable false, and when the "B" radio button checked I want to display new items with different number of items and clickable true.
How can I implement this?
I have tried this:

```
    private void setUpDailyRecycleView(List<IWeather> dailyWeathers){

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.daily_recylceview);
    CardAdapter cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this, dailyWeathers);
    CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.daily_card);
    cardView.setClickable(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);

    LinearLayoutManager verticalLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    verticalLayoutManger.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutManger);

}
```

and this :

```
    private void setUpDailyRecycleView(List<IWeather> dailyWeathers){

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.daily_recylceview);
    CardAdapter cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this, dailyWeathers);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);

    LinearLayoutManager verticalLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    verticalLayoutManger.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutManger);
    CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.daily_card);
    cardView.setClickable(true);

}
```

but a NullPointerException is thrown because the card view object is null.

Comment: do you try anything to archive this?

Comment: Yes, I tried to get the card view by id in the main class before and after calling and setting the adapter and layout manger but the card view object is still null and a NullPointerException is thrown

Comment: I don't understand about ' before and after calling ', anyway card view object null meaning there is some logic mistake. Post your code snippet for more help.

Comment: Can You provide your code plz

Comment: If your have "daily_card" as recycler view item you cannot initialize it here.It should be inside recycler adatper.

Comment: Edited, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You mean in onCreateViewHolder @Anonymous

Comment: I think you dint get me..I am asking whether the R.id.daily_card is present in activity xml or recycler view item xml?

Comment: Ok, It's a recycler view item @Anonymous

Comment: @AliHabbash then how can u initialize it inside activity?obviously it will null pointer exception because R.id.daily_card id is not present in activity.Instead initialize it inside oncreateView holder of the recycler view adapter

Comment: @Anonymous I'm new to card view. It's worked thank you so much. and repopulate the new items into the recycler will simply done by calling the above method with the new list right?